# configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable. Ubuntu 20.10 & R 3.6.3

Tags: 20.10

I had problems installing gdal in R v 3.6.3, showing the message on R terminal:

configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable

Comment: Please move answer to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Solved!
Using apt-get to install libgal have unsolved dependencies, solved them resulted in a system crash. After resolving the boot crash.

Used:

```
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:                                        
1)     default-libmysqlclient-dev [1.0.5ubuntu2 (groovy)]                   
2)     libmysqlclient-dev [8.0.21-1 (groovy)]                               
3)     libpq-dev [12.4-1 (groovy)]                                          

     Downgrade the following packages:                                      
4)     libmysqlclient21 [8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.10.2 (now) -> 8.0.21-1 (groovy)]
5)     libpq5 [12.5-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 (now) -> 12.4-1 (groovy)]              
6)     postgresql-client-12 [12.5-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 (now) -> 12.4-1 (groovy)]
```

Now I realized that the R updated from 3.6.3 to 4.0.2 automatically. It should not happen I don't know how to stop the automatic updates so I add the repository for bionic-cran35:

´´´´
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
´´´´

I disable all the downloads from internet (Cannonical, community and property). I'm not supposed to but I don't know how to stop that automatic update for R and giving me troubles again.

Comment: I should think that, on a general note, if you're going to deal with dev dependencies, you should use the latest version of R.

Comment: Thanks, I still do not know how to completely solve. Maybe a fresh restart. I'll do it finishing my tesis. Now I am surviving disabling all automatic updates.

Comment: I would suggest you visit the [rgdal CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) and look at *SystemRequirements*. Follow the instructions closely and visit the relevant pages pointed to from there. That was how I solved my own issue.